# Cygwin reports “-bash: /usr/bin/svn: Bad address”

Tags: svn, bash, cygwin

Upon

```
$ svn co http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/jetpack-easy-playlists/ jep/
```

or

```
$ svn --version
```

I get -bash: `/usr/bin/svn: Bad address`

```
$  ls -l /usr/bin/svn
```

gives me `-rwxr-xr-x 1 JFishwick Domain Users 189966 Mar 8 15:52 /usr/bin/svn`

I have tried removing /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll and reinstalling base, but with no luck.

EDIT: Futhermore,

```
$ type svn
svn is /usr/bin/svn
```

and

```
$ which svn
/usr/bin/svn
```

and

```
$ ldd $(which svn)
        ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/ntdll.dll (0x7c900000)
        kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/kernel32.dll (0x7c800000)
        cygsvn_client-1-0.dll => /usr/bin/cygsvn_client-1-0.dll (0x6f2c0000)
        cygsvn_ra-1-0.dll => /usr/bin/cygsvn_ra-1-0.dll (0x620c0000)
        cygsvn_ra_local-1-0.dll => /usr/bin/cygsvn_ra_local-1-0.dll (0x6b9c0000)
        cygsvn_repos-1-0.dll => /usr/bin/cygsvn_repos-1-0.dll (0x6b6c0000)
        cygsvn_fs-1-0.dll => /usr/bin/cygsvn_fs-1-0.dll (0x6e800000)
        cygsvn_fs_base-1-0.dll => /usr/bin/cygsvn_fs_base-1-0.dll (0x6c780000)
        cygsvn_delta-1-0.dll => /usr/bin/cygsvn_delta-1-0.dll (0x61bc0000)
        cygsvn_subr-1-0.dll => /usr/bin/cygsvn_subr-1-0.dll (0x6d680000)
        cygwin1.dll => /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll (0x61000000)
        cygz.dll => /usr/bin/cygz.dll (0x692c0000)
        cyggcc_s-1.dll => /usr/bin/cyggcc_s-1.dll (0x6bf40000)
        cygapr-1-0.dll => /usr/bin/cygapr-1-0.dll (0x69f70000)
        cyguuid-1.dll => /usr/bin/cyguuid-1.dll (0x542e0000)
        cygaprutil-1-0.dll => /usr/bin/cygaprutil-1-0.dll (0x69f50000)
couldn't open C:\cygwin\bin\svn
cannot load file
```

my $PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/IBM/CLIENT~1:/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/IBM/CLIENT~1/Shared:/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/IBM/CLIENT~1/Emulator:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Lenovo:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/WinSCP:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/QuickTime Alternative/QTSystem:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Google/Google Apps Sync:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Google/Google Apps Migration:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/CVSNT: C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin:/usr/lib/lapack
```

vs

```
$ $PATH
-bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/IBM/CLIENT~1:/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/IBM/CLIENT~1/Shared:/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/IBM/CLIENT~1/Emulator:/cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

[Further discussion and fact finding here.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10501)

Comment: Can you add the output of `type svn` and `ldd $(which svn)` to your post?

Comment: Also, can you echo your $PATH?

Answer (score 1):

Note the difference in paths:

```
$ type svn
svn is /usr/bin/svn

$ ldd $(which svn)
    ...
couldn't open C:\cygwin\bin\svn
cannot load file
```

When you use ldd, there's some sort of hard coded path to `C:\cygwin\bin` aka `/bin/` ... your executable actually resides in `/usr/bin/`

Just for giggles, I would try copying or moving svn into /bin, just to see if this will resolve the issue. If you copy rather than move, make sure that you move /bin ahead of /usr/bin in $PATH, so that this is actually what's getting called.

The reason that I asked about `$PATH` is that the mechanism that cygwin uses to translate between `C:` and `/cygdrive/c` gets stymied by double quotes... I was in the habit of putting quotes around my paths on the windows side, which caused problems with the paths in cygwin. When I saw an un-translated path name, it rang that mental bell... alas, that wasn't the problem here.

Comment: When I look in "C:\cygwin\usr\bin" there is absolutely nothing in there. In "C:\cygwin\bin" I see "svn.exe" and many other svn-related files. But no plain "svn" in either place. Am I maybe missing an alias?

Comment: In that case, I would try `$ ln /bin/svn.exe /usr/bin/`. I don't understand how `$type svn` can return `svn is /usr/bin/svn` if `/usr/bin/svn` doesn't exist. If you had run it before, you would see `svn is hashed (/usr/bin/svn)`... you can change things under the hood and still refer back to the hashed executable... but that isn't what's happening here. By the way, what does `$ which svn` give you, and is it different from `$ type svn`?

Comment: Both give me `/usr/bin/svn`. Also I get `ln: failed to create hard link '/usr/bin/svn.exe': File exists`. It's weird, when I look in windows at `C:\cygwin\usr\bin` it is completely empty, but `ls /usr/bin` returns long list of files, seemingly those in `/bin`.

Comment: What happens when you look in `/cygdrive/c/usr/bin`?

Comment: Also, run `$ file /usr/bin/svn.exe` just to make sure that it's actually a binary file, not a shell script or a tar file or something...

Comment: That directory doesn't exist. Do you mean `/cygdrive/c/cygwin/usr/bin`? And now I feel like I'm going crazy, because `ls /cygdrive/c/cygwin/usr/bin` shows nothing, but `ls /user/bin` gives me that long list of files. What am I missing? For `file /usr/bin/svn.exe` I get ` PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10501/discussion-between-barton-chittenden-and-two7s-clash)

Answer (score 1):

There is possibly a dll missing.  Try running svn.exe from the dos prompt vis:

c:>  **c:\cygwin\bin\svn.exe**

I got a pop-up indicating that cygproxy-1.dll was missing.  Re-installed anything with the word proxy in it and the problem went away.